# matching multiple elements with CSS not()

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have to change the style of everything on an entire page, except for a huge list of exempted elements. Apparently CSS `not()` doesn't support a comma syntax like this: `:not(p, div)`. Do I have to just make a huge list like the one below, repeating the style for each one, or is there a quicker solution?

```
:not(p){xyz}
:not(div){xyz}
:not(a){xyz}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
:not(p):not(div):not(a){xyz}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/MA3nM/

Comment: Thanks. I'll just search and replace to put that down a hundred times... Seems silly that there's no comma notation.

Comment: @Nate Glenn: Thankfully, that's coming in [Selectors 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation). Better late than never!

Comment: @BoltClock Interesting. That'll sure be nice. Here's another [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/21/sneak-peek-future-selectors-level-4/) for the future.